# Build and include .so file in a jar with maven

Tags: java, c++, maven

I have done some research in SO to find an answer for my question. However, I have not yet found a post that exactly matches with my requirements. I have the source code of a C++ library. The build is done with cmake. It creates a .so file that I need. I want to wrap this code in a java class and create a jar (which will have .so file) . Is this something I can do using maven? Any help will be greatly appreciated.